# PropertyChanged event is not firing

Tags: c#, paging, wpfdatagrid

I am implementing paging for DataGrid using `ObservableCollection<>`.
First time it correctly displays 10 records. When click on the `Next` button, it didn't show the second page. When I debug, I found that `PropertyChanged` event is not firing when I set currentpagenumber.

My code is

```
   ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> riskCollection = new ObservableCollection<RiskSettings>();
  private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<RiskSettings>> Pages;
    private ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> _ItemsSource;
    private ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> _CurrentPage;
  public RiskAlert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GeneratePages();
    }
   private void GeneratePages()
    {
        if (riskCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(riskCollection.Count / (double)ItemsPerPage);
            Pages = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<RiskSettings>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < PageCount; i++)
            {
                ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> page = new ObservableCollection<RiskSettings>();
                for (int j = 0; j < ItemsPerPage; j++)
                {
                    if (i * ItemsPerPage + j > riskCollection.Count - 1) break;
                    page.Add(riskCollection[i * ItemsPerPage + j]);
                }
                Pages.Add(page);
            }
            this.CurrentPage = Pages[0];
            this.CurrentPageNumber = 1;
        }
    }

  public int CurrentPageNumber
    {
        get { return _CurrentPageNumber; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentPageNumber = value;
            //if (PropertyChanged != null)
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPageNumber"));
        }
    }
 public ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return riskCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            riskCollection = value;
            GeneratePages();
        }
    }
 public ObservableCollection<RiskSettings> CurrentPage
    {
        get { return _CurrentPage; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentPage = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPage"));
        }
    }

    public int CurrentPageNumber
    {
        get { return _CurrentPageNumber; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentPageNumber = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPageNumber"));
        }
    }

    public int ItemsPerPage
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ItemsPerPageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsPerPageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsPerPageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsPerPage", typeof(int), typeof(RiskAlert), new UIPropertyMetadata(20));

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
```

I collected all data in riskCollection.My DataGrid Name is grdRiskAlerts
I binded as

```
    GeneratePages();
            this.ItemsSource = riskCollection;
            grdRiskAlerts.ItemsSource = CurrentPage;
            txtTotalRecs.Text = "Total : " + riskCollection.Count();
            //txtDispRecs.Text = CurrentPage.Count().ToString();
            txtNumOfPages.Text = this.CurrentPageNumber.ToString();
            totalRecords = riskCollection.Count();
            if (pageSize <= totalRecords)
            {
                if (totalRecords > 0)
                    txtDispRecs.Text = "Displaying 1 to " + CurrentPage.Count();
                else
                    txtDispRecs.Text = "Displaying 0 to " + CurrentPage.Count();
            }
```

For this paging stuff i followed one example from google
I do not know why propertychanged event is not firing.

Can any one help on this?

Ramki.

Comment: That paste doesn't contain any XAML, so we cannot see your bindings. You should insert the **relevant** bits of code into your question so that people can view them immediately without having to go to another site.

Comment: I am new to this forums.I removed unwanted code in my link[http://pastebin.com/twLjQ28Q]

Comment: That second paste is empty. You are not making it easy for people to help you... use the edit button under your question to include the code directly into your question.

Comment: Hi slugster,Now i edit and pasted the code.

Answer (score 4):

The clear problem is you are setting the value directly rather than updating the binding source. Look if you bind some source to a property then change that property manually, youy break the binding and thats why property change in not firing.

Comment: +1, Assigning the `CurrentPage` property directly to the `grid.ItemsSource` property **does not create a binding** - items added to the collection will show up, but changing the whole `CurrentPage` property will not show up in the grid.